# MySQL matching query performance on large dataset

Tags: mysql

Does anyone have experience with query of the form

```
select * from TableX where columnY = 'Z' limit some_limits
```

For example:

```
select * from Topics where category_id = 100
```

Here columnY is indexed, but it's not the primary key. ColumnY = Z could return an unpredictable number of rows (from zero to a few thousands).

I only wonder the case of quite large dataset, for example, more than 10 millions items in TableX. What is the performance of such query?

A little detail about the performance should be nice (I mean specific big-O analysis, for example).

Comment: If it's indexed all the hard work has been done. jump to category_id 100 read off limit number of record ids. Thats what indexes are for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the records found. If your query return a large number of records it may take time to load the browswer. And even larger return could make your browser unresponsive. But this is how you execute the query. The better solution for such problems could be limiting the query as you did with relevant limits. Further more instead of limiting manually you may use limit with loop till certain index and again start from following index in the case of programming. I am answering with the context of programming. Hope this answers your question

Comment: It's common knowledge and doesn't answer my question.